# Check if email attachment is password protected before sending

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I'm trying to check all my attachments before sending an email to see if they are password protected. Typically these will be Word, Excel or PowerPoint files.

I've got as far as seeing if there are attachments.

I don't know how to loop through each attachment in the mail file to see if each one is password protected.

```vb
Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim attachments2 As Outlook.attachments
Dim attachm As Outlook.Attachment

If Item.attachments.Count > 0 Then

    Set attachments2 = Item.attachments

    Set attachm = Item.Attachment

    For Each attachm In attachments2

    ' ***IM GUESSING CODE TO CHECK IF ATTACHMENTS ARE PROTECTED WOULD GO IN HERE?***

    Next

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please define 'protected'... i.e. For a Word document, do you mean 'protected with a password' or 'protected for form filling', or some other definition. Then you need to identify all of the types of files that you need to check because each may require a different approach.

Comment: Sorry - they're password protected, so you can't view the contents of the file without the right password first.

Comment: Is there more to your question than just 'see if password protected'? I can understand if you either want every attachment password protected, or want to make sure none are protected, then either allow or prevent sending.   Is the fact the file is password protected enough, or do you need to know the password? Your code can attempt to open each file, but more info is needed.

Comment: I'd just like the code to check the email for attachements and if there are -  to see if they're password protected, and if there's any that aren't to flag a warning that the email is about to send and give the option to cancel it being sent.

What I don't know how to VB code is how to check each attachment to see if they're password protected, grateful for any help here thanks.

Comment: I will submit some very raw code of how to check for passwords as an answer. In real life, I would call that Function, passing the path & filename, then have it determine the type of file and if it has a password. You could call it from your module. However, I have been unable to find out how to get the path name to the file in either where you have your code, or when the user attaches the file (that's where I believe the code should go). If you can get the path, great. Other file types could be added to check for passwords.

Answer (score 0):

The code below does not solve your issue, but does show how to check documents and databases to see if password protected. If you are able to obtain the file path, then this code could be modified to pass the path and filename, then return a flag to indicate PW status. Or just modify and embed this code in your module.

Revision 1:  Instead of trying to find the path of the file to check for a password, an alternate solution would be for your code to save the file to a temp folder, then delete when finished. The following line of code will give you a temp folder (i.e. C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp)

```
strFolder = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(2)
```

This idea was obtained from a post that allows you to rename attachments: http://www.flobee.net/rename-outlook-attachments-before-you-send-them/

Also, the OP need to consider how to implement/perform the password check. If the code is called 'automatically', then unless you have some rule to only check certain files, then your code will always check ALL attachments for ALL emails! I doubt that's what you want to happen. Perhaps a user button on the tool bar?

Original Code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function Check_For_Passwords()
Dim objWord     As Word.Application
Dim objWordDoc  As Word.Document
Dim sPath       As String
Dim sFileName   As String
Dim oAccess     As Access.Application

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap

    ' Set the following string to the path of your Word Document
    sPath = "C:\data\WP\"                   ' <<< CHANGE THIS!!
    sFileName = "Access.doc"                ' <<< CHANGE THIS!!
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False
    ' Use a fake password - if no password on doc, OK; If password protected will fail
    Set objWordDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(sPath & sFileName, , True, , "*****")
    'Err: 5408    The password is incorrect. Word cannot open the document.

    Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    oAccess.Visible = False
    sPath = "C:\data\Access\"                   ' <<< CHANGE THIS!!
    sFileName = "PWD_DB.mdb"                    ' <<< CHANGE THIS!!

    'If error, then database has password
    oAccess.DBEngine.OpenDatabase sPath & sFileName, False
    'Err: 3031    Not a valid password.

    Exit Function

Error_Trap:
    If Err.Number = 5408 Then
        MsgBox "Document has a password! Do whatever...  " & sPath & sFileName
    ElseIf Err.Number = 3031 Then
        MsgBox "Access DB has a password! Do whatever...  " & sPath & sFileName
    Else
        MsgBox "Unexpected error: " * Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: For future searchers who find this answer. I suggest you save the attachments in a designated folder so you know the path. Open the application based on the file extension, then once done with the password check kill the temporarily saved file.

Comment: @niton, I liked your idea so did some more searching and found a variation like you suggest. It involves saving the attachments to your temp folder, the deleting when finished. Since no changes are made, that will work just fine.  I added more info in the answer above.Thanks!